# How to install npm install xbox-controller in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, ubuntu

I have used johnny-five to blink a led with a button. I want to blink it with a button of the xBox pad so I found npm xbox-controller but I cannot install it in Ubuntu 14.04. I get this error:

```
**compilation terminated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/hidapi/hidapi/libusb/hid.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/villalpando/xbox/node_modules/node-hid/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-37-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "build" "install"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/villalpando/xbox/node_modules/node-hid
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.38
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-37-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "node-hid"
npm ERR! node v0.10.38
npm ERR! npm  v2.9.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! node-hid@0.3.2 install: `sh install.sh`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-hid@0.3.2 install script 'sh install.sh'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-hid package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     sh install.sh
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-hid
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/villalpando/xbox/npm-debug.log**
```

Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here http://www.codeitive.com/0zzejPjkVg/npm-fail-to-install-nodehid-faild-to-install-last-version-of-nodejs.html it seems that my node.js was just too old to support node-hid thanks